# What types of API do you offer with your Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, api, sdk

We have a 3-tier Delphi application written using RemObjects DataAbstract. Many of our customers are asking for an API so they can interact with it using their own applications.

The API must allow the clients to call methods with various parameters and return results ranging from simple parameters to whole datasets.

What types of API can you recommend and how difficult are they to implement?

Comment: It's very hard to give any answer to a question this generalized aside from "it depends."  First off, what exactly do the customers mean by "an API"?

Comment: @Mason - I've clarified the question a little. The customers need a method of accessing the functionality of our middle tier. We need a way for them to pass requests to our server and return the results.

Comment: I still wish Delphi had something equivalent to the WCF element of the Microsoft stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've written your application using RemObjects DataAbstract then you've got just about everything you need already waiting for you in your application.

RemObjects DataAbstract includes the RemObjects SDK which is one of the most flexible and easy ways to build an API available. The RemObjects SDK lets you expose methods methods to your customers in a multitude of ways from native binary RemObjects calls, to XML-RPC, to JSON, to SOAP, to a local DLL, to Windows Messages, to Named Pipes... even via SMTP/POP.

The beauty is that you'll be able to design one API and then easily expose it to your customers [via any or all of these different mechanisms](http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Smart_Services). Just design your API methods, then ask your customer how they'd like to be able to consume it, chances are RemObjects have a message/channel combination that matches their request.

Comment: After working with the SuperTcpChannel for so long I'd forgotten there were other options :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Publish the API as functions in a DLL. Easy enough to code, but limited by the DLL limits (only plain functions, etc.). Not easy to call from scripts, for example
2. Publish the API as COM objects. A bit more complex to implement (especially if you never used COM before), but very flexible. Can be easily called from scripts, if needed.
3. Use a standard generic RPC mechanism like SOAP or REST. Better suited for server, not difficult to implement, requires a "listener" active to receive the calls
4. Use your own protocol to communicate. Longer to implement, can be faster than SOAP or REST, but requires also more work on the customer side.

Comment: If you go with SOAP it's very easy for the customer to just import tyhe WSDL and 90% of the work is done. With a little effort you can generate annotations for the WSDL and a help file to go with it, which (once you have it set up) makes keeping the documentation up to date very easy. IME one of the key things to ensure that it's all working is to use the API yourselves. That way it's more likely to be usable, complete and working. I'm not a huge fan of raw DLL's or COM these days, SOAP and REST are much more usable.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the plain business logic API, I think it will be also a big advantage if the application offers APIs for generic tasks like:

- logging / audit trails
- monitoring (performance, statistics)
- rights administration
- basic administration (shutdown / go to maintenance mode)
- messaging (send notifications to users or applications)